# Is reactor-rabbitmq threadsafe

Tags: java, rabbitmq, project-reactor, reactor-rabbitmq

I am planning to use RabbitMQ client from https://projectreactor.io in my Java project. But from documentation (https://projectreactor.io/docs/rabbitmq/milestone/reference) not clear that Sender or Receiver is threadsafe. Can anyone help with answer?

Comment: The reactive paradigm implies that there is not shared hidden state. You compose your logic using pure functions. Thats why the question about thread safety is irrelevant. As there is no resource to be protected from concurrent modification.